# android reservation system app

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-imagebutton

I am making an android app for a reservation system for an office. I want it so that users can click on a seat to reserve it. Also I want the seats to be color coded once they are reserved. I only have a picture of the floor map to work with. How can I do that using an image and buttons?

Comment: You can use seperate graphics for the state of the seat (used or not) (setImageResource).  And you can put the "android:onClick" directly on the XML for each seat.  You can also add a TAG parameter to the XML so you can tell which one just got clicked.  that should get you started.

Comment: The problem is that I just have an image of the floor plan and so if I place a button for each seat then that would end up being a mess as there are around 50-60 seats on the map. Also, the position of each button can't be hard coded because of different screen sizes. Can you suggest any other ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer, as it seems this is really the right way to go.

Set up a relative layout.  You don't need an actual graphic of the floor plan.  That would complicate things in terms of screen sizes.  You will almost certainly have to allow for landscape/portrait either way.

You can use imageViews and create a grid of your entire layout.  Tag each of the images in the layout as row,column, like: 01, 02, 03, 11, 12, 13, etc, and indefinitely.  This way you'll know which image was clicked on.  Use, by default, the "available" state for each seat.  Create a secondary "unavailable" version of the graphic that you can swap in later.

When a user clicks on an image, use an onClick handler from the XML to call a function that checks the seat.  If it's available, run the steps to make it unavailable, and whatever other data you need to set.  If it's unavailable, do nothing.

I wrote a BubbleWrap popping game a few months ago that uses this exact sort of model, and it works great.  (i'd link it up here, but I do believe that remote linking/plugging is frowned upon here)

This whole answer is very much on the surface, as it is going to require research on the particulars.  But this should be enough to get you moving.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I'm actually gonna go ahead and use your solution and see what I can do with that. Is it possible for you to email me your code?

Comment: Ok, sure.  Just please accept my answer (the check mark).  Then, go to my profile and follow the link to my website.  From there you can contact me directly, and if you feel like it, you can grab the app I was talking about (in the Android Development section)

Answer (score 0):

A very easy implementatin would be, use relative layout, or if possible use gridlayout and arrange the buttons as the floor seats with numbers. when a button is clicked, reserve the seat, update some database or whatever to store information, and make that button disabled.